# Generate automatic unique id base on the blog title

Tags: jquery, rating

I am using polldaddys rating script on my blog site. I am just wondering if it is possible to modify the script using jquery to automatically add a unique id base on the title of my blog post?

This is the polldaddys rating script

```
<div id="pd_rating_holder_6508144"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
PDRTJS_settings_6508144 = {
        "id" : "6508144",
        "unique_id" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "permalink" : ""
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://i.polldaddy.com/ratings/rating.js"></script>
```

And my html:

```
<div class="headline">
<div><h1>This is my title</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="blogbody">
<div><p>The body content is here</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the title of your page then do this...

```
PDRTJS_settings_6508144 = {
    "id" : "6508144",
    "unique_id" : $(".headline h1").text(),
    "title" : "",
    "permalink" : ""
};
```